# Could you build a large drone out of aerogel, aerographene, or seagel?

Tags: air

Are there any engineering or material barriers to making one drone with a large, low-density foam? Could it stay afloat with solar panels, traditional drone propellers and motors, and what height could it stay at?

It seems like the "lighter than air" foams do not stay up in the air by themselves.

Would rain, wind, and sun break them down?

Are there any other reasons a single drone with a lot of such foams wouldn't last very long hovering in mid-air?

Comment: Apparently it doesn't float because graphite is denser than air, and aerogel is filled with air.

Comment: You've asked a [very similar question](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:iImJG9abkisJ:https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53097/could-large-sun-reducing-drones-be-made-out-of-aerographene-aerogel-or-seagel&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk) already, which you deleted. Aerogel is U$90 for a 6"x6" piece, how much would you need (can you afford), enough to block the sky? http://www.buyaerogel.com/product/airloy-x116-thin-films/

Comment: why not use a balloon?

Comment: It is already possible to build a drone out of balsa or something similar which is effectively "weightless" compared to the mass of other components like the motors and battery. If you do in fact assume the frame will be weightless, I suspect you'll find that the performance on paper will be good, but still in the ballpark of a drone with a regular frame.